# Number of unitary intersections between 2 sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given B ⊆ A fixed sets of sizes k ≤ n respectively. Find |{C ⊆ A / |C ∩ B|=1}|.

i.e. How many subsets of A have unitary intersection with B.

To solve it I wrote a python script to generate all possibilities (thinking it would help since I could look at the numbers and try to come with a formula).

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(1, len(s)+1)))

def create_set(n):
    return set(range(1,n+1))

for i in range(1, 9):
    print(str(i)+': ', end='')
    ps = powerset(create_set(i))
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        b = create_set(j)
        result = set()
        for p in ps:
            s = set(p)
            inter = s.intersection(b)
            if (len(inter) == 1):
                result.add(p)
        print(len(result), end='')
        print(' ', end='')
    print("")
```

```
1: 1 
2: 2 2
3: 4 4 3
4: 8 8 6 4
5: 16 16 12 8 5
6: 32 32 24 16 10 6
7: 64 64 48 32 20 12 7
8: 128 128 96 64 40 24 14 8
```

Searching for few of these terms I found this 2 sequences that are similar to mine but no equal (https://oeis.org/search?q=64+64+48+32+20+12+7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C$ be a set such that $|C\cap B|=1$. The only element $x$ of $C\cap B$ can be taken to be any of the $k$ elements of $B$. After choosing this element we can create $C$ by choosing any elements in $A-B$. So if $C$ has cardinality $r$ for $1\leq r\leq n$ we have that there are
$$k{n-k\choose r-1}.$$
The number of sets $C$ is then
$$\sum_{r=0}^{n}k{n-k\choose r-1}.$$

You can check that this coincides with the output of your program for each $n$ and $k$.

Comment: Ty. I spent like 3 hours trying to solve this and couldn't figure out

Comment: The sum should begin at $r=1$ (not $r=0$), and it might as well end at $r=n-k+1$ since all larger values of $r$ give $0$ for the binomial coefficient. The sum simplifies, by the binomial theorem, to $2^{n-k}$, as in Mitchell Spector's answer.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Binomial coefficients are typically defined to be $0$ for negative values. It doesn't make any difference, the formula is still correct. But yes, Mitchell's answer is simpler, yet not more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

$| A\setminus B\,|=n-k,$ so there are $2^{n-k}$ subsets of $A\setminus B.$

To form a set whose intersection with $B$ is a singleton, each of the $k$ elements of $B$ can be paired with any of the $2^{n-k}$ subsets of $A\setminus B.$

So the cardinality of $\{ C \subseteq A \mid C \cap B \text{ is a singleton} \}$ is $$\large k\cdot2^{n-k}.$$